# How to set color for nodes based on normalized random float attribute using Networkx and Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, nodes, networkx

Using Networkx, I have built a tree-like graph whose nodes each have a float attribute 'hc', which varies between 0 and 1, and is attributed at random to each node. For example, node 1 has 'hc' = 0.53 while node 2 has 'hc' = 0.47.

I would like to assign a color to each node based on the value of 'hc', preferentially in a way such that 0 corresponds to red and 1, to deep purple (similar to the jet colormap, see miscellaneous section in [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) ). Since my code is rather long and confusing I will not copy it here, so please use the code of this random network below as a reference. The part that assigns the 'hc' values is literally the same one I used with my tree.

```
G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(20, 0.1)

lower,upper = 0,1 # Parameters to normalize the x-axis of the gaussian
mean_hc = 0.5 # Mean value of hc atribute
devi_hc = 0.1   # Standard Deviation of hc atribute

gaussian_hc = stats.truncnorm((lower - mean_hc) / devi_hc, (upper - mean_hc) / devi_hc, loc=mean_hc, scale=devi_hc)

for i in G:
  G.nodes[i]['hc'] =  gaussian_hc.rvs()
  # The hc atributes have 14 digits. Use G.nodes[i]['hc'] = round(gaussian_hc.rvs(),3) for better performance

colour_aux = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'hc') # List of values of 'hc' of each node respectively
colour_aux[n] # 'hc' value of n'th node

print(G.nodes.data()) # Print all nodes' data
pos = graphviz_layout(G, prog="dot")
plt.figure(figsize=(30, 30))
nx.draw(G, pos) # Delete the node colour if colour not necessary
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NetworkX` uses a list of colors (or values) the same length as the number of nodes to assign colors to the nodes with the `node_color` argument.

If colors are passed in, `NetworkX` uses those directly.  If values are passed in, `NetworkX` maps those to a colormap defined in the `cmap` argument.  See the [documentation here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html) for more information.

The list needs to be in the same order as the nodes, so I find that it's always safest (though probably not always necessary) to generate the list of colors based on the order that `NetworkX` has the nodes in that can be found by calling `G.nodes()`.

So for your case, I'd do the following that gets the node's `hc` attribute for every node in the graph and ensures that the order is consistent with what `NetworkX` has internally:

```
colorlist = [G.nodes[node]['hc'] for node in G.nodes()]
```

Then when you actually want to draw your graph, `NetworkX` will be expecting a `Matplotlib` colormap.  Assuming you have `Maplotlib` imported as `mpl`, the following should do the trick:

```
nx.draw(G, pos = pos, node_color = colorlist, cmap = mpl.colormaps['jet'])
```

Other colormaps can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html) and `plt.cmap.jet` would work as well for `cmap`.

Comment: Had to import `matplotlib.cm` and use `cmap = cm.get_cmap("jet")`, but it worked as intended. Thank you kindly.